# How to install apt packages on a network share?

Tags: package-management

I want to provide some applications with NFS. The actual solution is to compile applications with --prefix to set the installation path.

The problem is that I manage a huge collection of applications and when they need to be upgraded, I need to do it manually for each one.

Theses applications can't be installed locally.

So I'm searching for a way to let a package manager do upgrades, but on a network share.

I was thinking about create an lxc container, network shared, but I need applications to be in the host's $PATH.

Is there any way, as complicated as it could be?

Comment: "The problem is that I manage a huge collection of applications and when they need to be upgraded, I need to do it manually for each one." There might be other options besides using a network share (which in my experience can be a pain). Can you describe in more detail your use case? Are these applications you created and/or packaged? Are they part of your distribution? And what is your distribution? If you are in control of the upgrade path, setting up automatic upgrades might be an option.

Comment: I have two way to install apps : first one is to add a package to my ansible playbook, app is installed locally and packages are cached by our proxy server to make clients get the package locally after the first download. But when i full deploy a new client, ansible take a long to apply the playbook, so i want to make it as lighter as possible. Second one is as i said, compiling the soft on the network share. I dont know other way to install a soft : apt throught ansible or compiling on the network share

Comment: Clients are under ubuntu, i already use automatic updates for apt packages, the only problem i want to resolv is how put packages on a network share.

Comment: Have you looked into `apt-cacher-ng`. I started to use this about a month ago and have not had any problems. My Internet network traffic has decreased and my machines are updated daily.

Comment: As i said, the problem is to not store on the local disk but on a nfs share. And 1 time for all, upgrade packages with apt. I already use cache to download packages only one time with the actual solutions. But every clients needs to install these packages on their local storage.